# i want to get value from the form using javascript before submit

Tags: php, javascript, sql, forms

I want to get value from input text form and send it to php before submit.

Ex:
PHP FILE:

```
$do="FORM VALUE HERE";     //HERE IS $_POST['search'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='$do'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $code=$row['code_number'];
  }
```

HTML:

```
<script >
HERE WHAT I WANT TO DO
<script />
```

FORM:

```
<form action="view_results.php?code=<? echo $code ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="search" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="search" />
<form />
```

So, with this example I want to get $do=$_POST['search'] before clicking to submit botton so I can select the result from mySQL to view it in the next page.

Thanks

Comment: There is no need for any Javascript here - just get the value from `$_POST['search']` and display it on the next page. Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: But escape your data using `mysql_rea_escape_string`, please!

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the form's submit event, cancel it, grab the form value you want, make your PHP post, and when *that's* done, go back and submit your form.

```
<form id="form1" action="view_results.php?code=<? echo $code ?>" method="post">

document.forms["form1"].onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //cancel form submit

    var searchValue = this.search.value;

    var self = this;
    //post searchValue to your PHP page using your favorite JS library, 
    //then in the call back, submit your form with self.submit();
};
```

Comment: i have no expariance in javascript, Can you Just tell me what the $do=.... on your code, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="view_results.php?code=<? echo $code ?>" method="post" onsubmit="beforeSubmit(event)">
   <input type="text" name="search" /><br />
   <input type="submit" value="search" />
<form />

<script >
   //HERE WHAT I WANT TO DO

   function beforeSubmit(event){

       event.preventDefault();

       var form = event.currentTarget;

       // form.search.value will give the text in search

   }
<script />
```